# PayPal Express Checkout Trial Period - payment delayed by up to 24 hours?

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

New client - in Malaysia - using our CMS platform.

She has a $297 Trial Period set up for her product - using our fully integrated PayPal Express Checkout system. After the Trial Period of 30 days, her members pay a $7/mo. recurring fee.

Everything works flawlessly - from checkout to profile set up, member area access to account record...

Except...

The trial period doesn't charge immediately and doesn't show in either her PayPal or the buyers PayPal for up to 24 hours.

Here are my questions:

1. PayPal states that Trial periods may take up to 24 hours to process, especially in markets like Singapore or Malaysia - is this, more than likely, our issue?
2. Time Zones - our client is obviously in Malaysia time zone - our servers are on on US Eastern and PayPal is in US Pacific. We've added time zone variations to get our servers and the client's time zones to match (using UTC) - but payments for Trial Periods still delay - not uniformly by the hour or minute, but variable times to post.

All transactions complete correctly within 24 hours - but, it's confusing to both our platform user and her members.

Is this a common issue and can it be solved or is this a PayPal SOP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not related to software development

Comment: If time zones are not related to software development and if PayPal questions about integrating their API are not allowed here - I think PayPal should re-evaluate using this platform as it's sole developer's forum/board.

This is a legitimate DEVELOPER question regarding time zones and API integration for Express Checkout. 

If you want only posts related to custom codes you wrote yourself, then legitimate questions about any frameworks or API integrations should all be disallowed.

Comment: I'm assuming you're working with Recurring Payments in Express Checkout, right?  If you can provide a sample of your CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request I can review it for you and see if there's anything I would recommend adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Angel,

```
I developed it in YII framework, Yes you are right I am using Recurring payment NVP API using Express checkout in Paypal. here is a code, 

`
      'EC-55C39358W5921893B',
        'PAYERID' => 'ZHM83TJRY68YJ',
        'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
        'DESC' => 'Recurring Payment',
        'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
        'AMT' => '100.00',
        'PROFILESTARTDATE' => '2015-02-09T17:54:21Z',
        'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Day',
        'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => '3',
        'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES' => '5',
        'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' => '3',
        'PAYERSTATUS' => 'verified',
        'TRIALBILLINGPERIOD' => 'Month',
        'TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY' => '1',
        'TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES' => '1',
        'TRIALAMT' => '30.00',
       );
            $datails = $paypal->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile($paymentInfo);
            if ($paypal->isCallSucceeded($datails)) {
              echo 'Success';
            }
?>
`
```

Comment: Hi can we set paypal trail period less then a day..?